# Logitech Mouse G502 Mouse, repeated disconnection

Tags: windows-10, mouse

My mouse was working fine, I kept it connected overnight on my laptop and they were both on. The next morning the mouse kept disconnecting and connecting repeatedly (1 sec connected, 1 sec disconnected). It plays the disconnected sound on loop. The computer can successfully identify it as logitech G502 through Logitech GHub.

I have updated drivers, restarted the computer, unpluggedd and replugged in the mouse, disabled power management on USB, installed Logitech G driver, the USB ports work for other devices, the logitech mouse displays the same issue when connected to other computers.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, at first I thought it was software but when trying to connect with another pc the same thing happened, so I decided to open it and see what happened, the mouse was very dirty and had humidity since sometimes I put wet clothes on it I just passed a brush with alcohol to everything and solved.
it is very easy to disassemble it with any video on youtube

Answer (score 1):

Anybody who finds this. I had the same probably when first installing a G203 mouse. I found out that I plugged it into the USB 2.0 by mistake. Plug it into USB3.0 and all good.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the mouse. Then go to settings -> devices -> remove device. Then plug back in & let it rediscover & re-install drivers etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution that works for me, but it does keep reconnecting after a computer restart.
Go into settings > Devices and then to your right-click on > devices and printers under the related setting tab.

(Keep your mouse plugged in and maybe mute your laptop/PC so you don't go insane) Now you can see your device at the top of the screen. Right-click it and press 'Remove Device' now just sit and wait for it to re-discover the device and it should be fine until restart.

Answer (score 0):

Start -> write down Device Manager -> click on it -> Go to Universal Serial Bus Controller -> Look for USB Root Hub -> Right click on properties -> Go to Power Management and uncheck the box!